# How do i cover the image on navbar as well?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to simply make the image to cover the navbar as well, but I'm really confused on how to do it right now.

The picture

[image]

currently the navbar and the the image are separate, if possible i want the background of the navbar to be the image as well

Html Code

```
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Full Width Image Header -->
    <header class="header-image">
        <div class="headline">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>join our movement!</h1>
                <!-- <h3>Join Now</h3> -->
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Join Now</button>
                <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Medium</button> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Css code

```
.header-image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("/images/cloud6.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Use z-index and positioning, then set opacity so it's see through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the navbar class background to transparent `.navbar { background : transparent; }`

set a negative margin to the header image like below;
`.header-image { margin-top : -40px};` as an example

Comment: Tried it but the image didn't cover the background though

Comment: you may want to add negative top margin for the header image though, I'll update my answer and see if it works

Comment: If i scroll down, how do i change the background again?

Comment: Don't worry already solved it, need to use jquery thanks anyway

Comment: that would require you to use jQuery or javascript to do that :) And what you mean by change background again? Set its margin-top to original value of 0? If so in jQuery you could do $(".header-image").css({"margin-top" : 0});

Answer (score 0):

You can try put navbar into header-image, and set background of navbar is none or transparent.

```
<header class="header-image">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     ...
    </nav>
    <div class="headline">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>join our movement!</h1>
            <!-- <h3>Join Now</h3> -->
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Join Now</button>
            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Medium</button> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I did this, but the image doesn't cover the navbar, instead it became white color

Comment: I tried set background of navbar same to header-image and make navbar overlaps header-image on top, when scroll down you don't need to set background of navbar again.